# python cgi script mysql module missing error when running it to xampp

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

i created a html file that send data to a python script and store data to mysql database

```
    this is my html code

    <body>
    <form method='post' action='dump.py' >
    Name:<input type='text' name='name' /><br/>
    Age:<input type='text' name='age' /><br/>
    Phone:<input type='text' name='phone' /><br/>
    Emailid:<input type='text' name='email' /><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Save'>
    </form>
    </body>
```

my python code to handle the post request is

```
#!C:\Users\Development\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe 
import cgi
import mysql.connector
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue("name")
age  = form.getvalue("age")
phone = form.getvalue("phone")
email = form.getvalue("email")

try:
    mysql_connection=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user='root', password='', database='employee')
    mysql_handler=mysql_connection.cursor()
    mysql_query="insert into register (name,age,phone,emailid) values('{0}',{1},{2},'{3}')".format(name,age,phone,email)
    mysql_handler.execute(mysql_query)
    if(mysql_handler.rowcount >= 1):
       mysql_connection.commit()
       print("Record Inserted")
    mysql_connection.close()
except:
    mysql_connection.rollback()
    print("Error occured")
```

after running it i get a blank page so look into xampp apachy error.log it says  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' this is what i am facing currently

system is am using windows 10 my xampp version is 8.0

Comment: Do you have the correct MySQL module installed?

Comment: i am actually new to python basically i am a php developer i need to install it in where pycharm ? how to check it is installed or not

Comment: If you don't remember installing it, you probably haven't. I don't use PyCharm, so I'm not sure how to install external modules with it, but it's easy to do on the command line. Just make sure your Python installation is on your `$PATH$`, and run `python -m pip install mysql-connector-python`. You *should* be good to go after that. There's tons of information on [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io) out there, so just Google any errors you may get.